# Check avaliable space by getDataDirectory() and getRootDirectory() is not same

Tags: android, android-storage

I try to check available space on my android phone by using `getDataDirectory().getPath()` and `getRootDirettory().getAbsolutePath()` and I got these results,

Using `getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

```
StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    Log.w("Path", String.valueOf(Environment.getRootDirectory()) );
    Log.w("Path", Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    long free_memory = statFs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong();
    Log.d("Available byte by Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath(): ", String.valueOf(free_memory/1048576));
```

Logcat:

> W/Path: /system
>
> W/Path: /system
>
> W/Available byte by Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath()::
>   91

---

Using `getRootDirectory().getPath()`

```
statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    Log.w("Path", String.valueOf(Environment.getDataDirectory()) );
    Log.w("Path", Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    long free_memory02 = statFs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * statFs.getBlockSizeLong();
    Log.d("Available byte by Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath(): ", String.valueOf(free_memory02/1048576));
```

Logcat:

> W/Path: /data
>
> W/Path: /data
>
> W/Available byte by Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath():: 21426
>   MB or 20.924 GB

but when I check available space from setting in my phone in only show: **20.34 GB**

What is the best accurate way to check available space in my phone and why `getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` and `getDataDirectory.getPath()` not give the same space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best accurate way to check available space

It is better to use **[`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)** for checking available memory.

There are **[different partitions](https://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/android-partitions-explained-boot-system-recovery-data-cache-misc/)** in Internal storage.

**/data** partition : Has user data only. **`//getDataDirectory()`**

**/system** partition : Holds the core Android OS. **`//getRootDirectory()`**

> why getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath() and
>   getDataDirectory().getPath() not give the same space?

Because they are different directories.

You can use

```
  final StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
  long totalinternal = (long) stat.getBlockSize() * (long) stat.getBlockCount();
  long available = (long) stat.getBlockSize() * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
```